# How to send data from bootstrap collapable component to model when users click on each component in bootstrap html?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a career page where there is collapsable bootstrap components which is used to show the positions that are available now. When users clicks on apply in each component i want to show model with particular position he/she wanted on Model dialog.

I want to show the position title on model when user clicks on a particlar component, how to do this with jquery.

Thank in advance

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="" data-id="Full-stack-developer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-link" type="button">
            Full Stack Developer
          </button>
          <p style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">Canada, USA</p>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="description-box">
                <h4>Job Description</h4>
                <p style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum totam saepe, vitae voluptatibus doloribus dolorum libero delectus cum ipsa dolor quidem, ad officia vero expedita. Explicabo odit sequi soluta nostrum!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="description-box">
                <h4>Requirements</h4>
                <ul style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;">
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Master Degreee</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Strong Knowldege in Javascript</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">ReactJs and NodeJs</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">MVC Pattern</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Master Degreee</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Alogorithms and Data Structures</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
              <div class="description-box">
                <button style="font-size: 18px;" id="fullstack" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="btn btn-primary">Apply Now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button">
            XR ENGINEER
          </button>
          <p style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">Dublin</p>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="description-box">
                <h4>Job Description</h4>
                <p style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum totam saepe, vitae voluptatibus doloribus dolorum libero delectus cum ipsa dolor quidem, ad officia vero expedita. Explicabo odit sequi soluta nostrum!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="description-box">
                <h4>Requirements</h4>
                <ul style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;">
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Master Degreee</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Strong Knowldege in Javascript</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">ReactJs and NodeJs</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">MVC Pattern</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Master Degreee</li>
                  <li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">Alogorithms and Data Structures</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
              <div class="description-box">
                <button style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-primary">Apply Now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">You are applying for: <b>Full stack developer</b></p>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Name</label>
                  <input style="height: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="please enter name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Email</label>
                  <input style="height: 40px;" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="please enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="6" type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="please enter message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 100px; border-style: dotted; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                  <input type="file">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the job offerings into a datastructure and use that to fetch the required information on the button click:

```js
function showTitle(title) {
    const titleElement = $("#job-title-replace");
    const hiddenInputElement = $("#some-hidden-input");
    titleElement.html(title);
    hiddenInputElement.val(title);
  }

$(document).ready(function() {

  const accordionElement = $("#accordionExample");
  

  const jobOffers = [{
      title: "Fullstack engineer",
      location: "Canada, USA",
      dataId: "fullstack-engineer",
      dataTarget: "collapseOne",
      requirements: [
        "Master Degree",
        "Strong Knowldege in Javascript",
        "ReactJs and NodeJs",
        "MVC Pattern",
        "Algorithms and Data Structures"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "XR Engineer",
      location: "Dublin",
      dataId: "xr-engineer",
      dataTarget: "collapseTwo",
      requirements: [
        "Master Degree",
        "Strong Knowldege in Javascript",
        "ReactJs and NodeJs",
        "MVC Pattern",
        "Algorithms and Data Structures"
      ]
    }
  ];

  function getNewElement(jobOffer) {
    let requirements = "";
    jobOffer.requirements.forEach(requirement => {
      requirements += `<li style="padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px; color: #000;">${requirement}</li>`
    });

    return `<div class="card">
    <a href="" data-id="${jobOffer.dataId}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${jobOffer.dataTarget}" aria-expanded="true"
      aria-controls="${jobOffer.dataTarget}">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button style="font-size: 18px;" class="btn btn-link" type="button">
            ${jobOffer.title}
          </button>
          <p style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">${jobOffer.location}</p>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div id="${jobOffer.dataTarget}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="description-box">
                <h4>Job Description</h4>
                <p style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum
                  totam saepe, vitae voluptatibus doloribus dolorum libero delectus cum ipsa dolor quidem, ad officia
                  vero expedita. Explicabo odit sequi soluta nostrum!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="description-box">
                <h4>Requirements</h4>
                <ul style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;">
                  ${requirements}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
              <div class="description-box">
                <button style="font-size: 18px;" id="fullstack" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
                  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showTitle('${jobOffer.title}')">Apply Now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
  }

  

  const newHtml = jobOffers.map(jobOffer => getNewElement(jobOffer));
  accordionElement.html(newHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <!-- This will be filled in by jQuery -->
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">You are applying for: <b id="job-title-replace">Full stack
            developer</b></p>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Name</label>
                  <input style="height: 40px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="please enter name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Email</label>
                  <input style="height: 40px;" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="please enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="6" type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="please enter message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 100px; border-style: dotted; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                  <input type="file">
                </div>
                <input id="some-hidden-input" name="some-hidden-input" value="" hidden>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I would like to add that at this point it might be better to just use a frontend library like React or Vue.

*EDIT: I have added code that will also set the value of a hidden input field.*

Comment: One more thing, How the value will sent through the hidden text field, Is there any way to pupulate the value in input hidden field

Comment: Sure, which field is the hidden one?

Comment: I have make an extra hidden field in the form, so when user submit the form the value which users selects (Job Title) should goto backend.

Comment: I have updated the code to include (and fill) this hidden input field